# Ruby gsub return value

Tags: ruby

Just started with Ruby, and got stuck up with inline edit constructs:

```
v1="SO"
print v1.gsub!(/\W/,"").reverse
v2="SO!!"
print v2.gsub!(/\W/,"").reverse
```

`v1.gsub!` results in nil. Why? `v2.gsub!` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key here is that you're using the mutating version of `gsub`, `gsub!`, which modifies the actual string it is called on. As for what it returns, [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) says it best:

> Performs the substitutions of [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) in place, returning `str`, or `nil` if no substitutions were performed.

You should either use the non-mutating version, `gsub`, if you don't actually wish to modify the string it is called on:

```
print v2.gsub(/\W/, "").reverse
```

Or you can do the substitution before printing the variable:

```
v2.gsub!(/\W/, "")
print v2.reverse
```

Or, in Ruby 1.9, you can use [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
print v1.tap { |v1| v1.gsub!(/\W/, "") }.reverse
```